# See what "block" the player is looking at

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera, sdl

I'm creating a game where the world is formed out of cubes (like in Minecraft), but there's just one small problem I can't put my finger on. I've created the world, the player, the camera movement and rotation (glRotatef and glTranslatef). Now I'm stuck at finding out what block the player is looking at.

EDIT: In case I didn't make my question clear enough, I don't understand how to cast the ray to check for collision with the blocks. All the blocks that I'm drawing are stored in a 3D array, containing the block id (I know I need to use octrees, but I just want the algorithm to work, optimization comes along the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is a drawing/rendering API, not some kind of game/graphics engine. You tell it to draw stuff, and that's what it does.

Tests like the one you intend are not covered by OpenGL, you've to implement them either yourself or use some library designed for this. In your case you want to test the world against the viewing frustum. The exact block the player looks on can be found by doing a ray geometry intersection test, i.e. you cast a ray from your player position into the direction the player looks and test which objects intersect with that ray. Using a spatial subdivision structure helps speeding things up. In the case of a world made of cubes the most easy and efficient structure is a octree, i.e. one large cube that gets subdivided into 8 sub-cubes of half the containing cube's edge length. Then those subcubes are divided and so on.

Traversing such a structure is easily implemented by recursive functions – don't worry about stack overflow, since already as litte as 10 subdivisions would yield 2^10^3 = 2^30 sub-sub-...-sub-cubes, with a requirement of at leat 8GB of data to build a full detailed mesh from them. But 10 function recursion levels are not very deep.

Comment: Huh? OpenGL provides multiple mechanisms that can help with this, from the deprecated "selection mode" to reading the depth buffer to reading a separate attribute buffer holding object IDs.

Comment: Well yes you can do this. But what you're actually doing is in a brute force approach render stuff to the framebuffer and then read what ended up there. Personally I consider OpenGL a pure drawing API and depending on the desired test sending a ray into the scene graph on the CPU is simpler and causes less overhead than going through the whole render pipeline. Especially in a minecraft like environment a ray→octree intersection test is dead simple; you'd have to traverse the octree for rendering anyway, but testing if a ray goes through a octree node takes less work then rendering that node.

Comment: Where OpenGL actually can help is determinining the exact position of where, say the user clicked with the mouse. In some way, determinining  "where the user looks" is the same problem. However just identifying, which object got picked/looked on usually is more efficiently done by looking at the scene graph (bounding volumes).

Comment: I agree that using OpenGL is a lot of extra unneeded computation.  But it's extra computation that's done at essentially no cost during the normal rendering process.

Comment: @datenwolf So, how can I "send" that ray at the scene graph? I'm barely scratching the surface of OpenGL, so sorry if my questions seem a little silly. I've been recently trying to draw a cube where the camera is looking at, but to no success.

Comment: Using OpenGL: Method (1): Render the scene with each block in a own color identifying the block. Read the pixel in the screen center using glReadPixels interpret the obtained pixel colour as block ID. Method (2): After rendering the scene read the screen center's pixel depth value, feed this through gluUnProject, giving you the world coordinate of the read pixel. In both cases you've to render the full scene - or you determine what's visible and what's not beforehand (frustum culling), but that already does what you want, telling what's viewed. That's why I say: Don't use OpenGL for this.

Comment: The ray intersection method is not done using OpenGL but by good old numerical linear algebra. http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/raytrace/rtinter3.htm combine this with a octree (which you should use anyway to send only visible cubes to OpenGL) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree Technically the whole viewing volume (frustum) culling – you should really do this, but operates a step before OpenGL – gives you the ray intersection test almost for free.

Answer (score 0):

First imagine a vector from your eye point in the direction of the camera with a length equal to the player's "reach".  If I remember correctly the reach in Minecraft is about 4 blocks (or 4 meters).  For every block in your world that could intersect that vector (which can be as simple as a 3D loop over a cube of blocks bounded by the min/max x/y/z values for your reach vector) cast a ray at the cube (if it's not air) to see if you hit it.  Raycasting at an AABB (axis aligned bounding box) is pretty straightforward and you can Google that algorithm.  Now sort the results by distance and return the block that hit the ray first.

Comment: Yeah. I have problems imagining the vector from the eye to the direction of the camera.. That part I can't seem to understand, and after that. I've been searchin around Google for Raycasting, but it just got me more confused.